# Make ML Engine request for image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to craft the correct request for my ML Engine model.

I get

```
$ gcloud ml-engine predict --model=plantDisease01 --json-instances=request-float32.json  
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, 
details=\"Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,50176], In[1]: [25088,256]\n\t [[Node: dense_1_1/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=[[?,256]], transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0\"](_arg_dense_1_input_1_0_0, dense_1_1/kernel/read)]]\")"
}
```

I generated a sample request with

```
python -c 'req = []; [req.append(0.2) for i in range(224*224)]; print(req)' &> request-float32.json
```

I generated the protocol buffer version with the following snippet

```
# convert keras model to mlengine model
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model, Sequential
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder as saved_model_builder
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants, signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model.signature_def_utils_impl import predict_signature_def

# reset session
K.clear_session()
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

# disable loading of learning nodes
K.set_learning_phase(0)

# load model
model = load_model('vgg16_no_augmentation.h5')
config = model.get_config()
weights = model.get_weights()
new_Model = Sequential.from_config(config)
new_Model.set_weights(weights)

# export saved model
export_path = 'mlengine-03' + '/export'
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={'foo-input': new_Model.input},
                                  outputs={'serve': new_Model.output})

with K.get_session() as sess:
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=sess,
                                         tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
                                         signature_def_map={
                        signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature})
    builder.save()
```

the model is this one https://github.com/ClaudeCoulombe/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.3-using-a-pretrained-convnet.ipynb upto cell 6

(I deviated slightly from the linked model, it uses input_dim=4 * 4 * 512, I used a larger one)

I know 25088 = 7 * 7 * 512, and this is the input_dim in the model. But I'm not sure how I should go from an image to a file with 25,088 floats in it?

Comment: The idea is that you first pass the images through the feature extractor (the convolutional base of the model), store those features (of shape 7*7*512) in your case, and pass those through a classifier. What model exactly are your saving with your code? The convolutional model, or the classifier?

The VGG model from the notebook expects images of shape (150, 150, 3). Assuming that you are trying to request a prediction from the convolutional model, perhaps you want to populate your request json with (224*224*3) floats instead of (224*224)?

Comment: no the input is almost certainly 7*7*512 because that's what the input_dim is to the first layer of the model. I think you're right though, I'd need a copy of the convolutional_base in the client app in order to create the input for inference

Comment: the 2nd example in the kernel integrates the conv_base into the model, I'll try using that instead.

Comment: @HarryMoreno You mentioned that the input_dim is 25088 and the error message makes it clear that it is expecting that size of input. Is your question how to take an actual image and convert it to a valid json request for the service with the correct size?

Comment: the question was how to craft a request that would work with the model. I ended up using the 2nd version of the model in the kernel, this allows us to send over the raw image to the model host and the host can preprocess the image before using the model on the input.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge was that you have to use the convolutional base on the image client-side and then send the extracted features to the model hosting service.

I opted instead to use a version of the model which integrates the convolutional base into the model. Then I created a simple api that runs the model, accepts image upload and resize it before feeding the image into the model.

It's visible at https://github.com/morenoh149/simple-keras-rest-api/tree/hm-plant-model